# iPhone: Translucent navigation bar inside a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

Here it is.
I have a UINavigationController inside a UITabBarController.
Is there a way to set the navigation bar translucent??
I tried, programmatically, to set it like this:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

but nothing changes.
I even tried to log the translucent value and it is actually YES but the bar is still completely opaque.
The view behind the nav bar covers the full screen, i can even see it under the (translucent) status bar. I really don't understand.
All this happens only if the nav controller is inside the tabbar controller.

EDIT:
Guess what?  It was xcode screwing up my nib file ...
I recreated the xib from scratch and it works as expected.
Thanks anyway

Comment: I've faced the same problem and I have no xib. In my case it was setted  background color. it must be transparent.

Answer (score 6):

You are setting the wrong property:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Comment: @Luigi: I just tried it and it definitively worked, plus its not deprecated (on 4.0) and has been available science 2.0. I would recommend you read the [documentation on UINavigationBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html) and download [this source code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007418) from apple.

Comment: @Zebs Definitely deprecated now: [`UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent`
Deprecated. Use UIBarStyleBlack and set the translucent property to YES instead.](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to change navigation bar style for my UITabBarController based app recently using XCode 4.2.1. The code given by Zebs is wrong in this context. If you are working with navigationController that you create by yourself, then it'd be ok, but the thing is, the navigationController created by the UITabBarController is created by UITabBarController hence the correct code is:

```
self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

Note we use **moreNavigationController** instead of just **navigationController**. Hope that helps everyone who is facing the same problem.